# Get Google Analytics Data without Client Secrets

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am looking to make a web based app which creates a monthly report that has Google Analytics information in i.e. organic searches etc. Some clients will have their own Google Analytics accounts and wont be own mine.

I managed to get the OAuth 2 authorization working with my account however it wont work for clients as I needed to get the client_secret.json file from Google Developers website.  I have seen a service like cyfe.com which just gets the google login information and outs the Google Analytics information in graphs and such.

Does anyone know how they manage this is possible without getting  the client_secret.json file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oAuth2 is designed to let you access to users data with their permission, without requiring to access their password.

You should use your own `client Id` and `client secret`, these identify your application, not your users ("client" here means client of the API).

You then need to create an interface where users can allow your application to access to their data, from this you'll get an `access token`, allowing to your application to access to Google Analytics data of your user on their behalf.

Read "[Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps)", and identify the scenario that matches to what you want to achieve.

I strongly suggest that you use a library managing the authentication flow, you don't need to reinvent the wheel. Here's a list from Google: [Google API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/).

Comment: Thank you for explaining it like that. It makes much more sense now than when trying to read through the Google Analytics explanation.